# Next steps for debugging lmdbjni access violation

Tags: scala, java-native-interface, lmdb

I am using this fork of LMDBjni:https://github.com/deephacks/lmdbjni to
form the backend of a medium-sized databases project in scala.

I've been hitting a `EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005)` in the JNI code for this LMDB, and would like to know whether there is anything obvious I'm doing wrong or what the next steps for debugging should be. I'm not exactly sure what I'm looking for, so I'm going to list as much information about what's happening as I can and hope the symptoms make sense to somebody.

The access violation occurs in a Database with a single key mapping to a single 8-byte value, on approximately the 4000th access to that database (the exact number appears to be the same with each run), suggesting that this is a deterministic problem.

I believe I only have one thread accessing the database at a time, and regardless, in my understanding, as the operation is wrapped in a transaction, concurrent accesses should not matter anyway.

By looking through stack traces and printing values the issue comes from this generic construction I wrote for building transactions.

My code that causes the issue is here, the crash occurs in the marked `db.get()` call:

```
def transactionalGetAndSet[A](
    key: Key,
    db: Database
)(
    compute: A => LMDBEither[A]
 )(
    implicit sa: Storeable[A], 
    env: Env
 ): LMDBEither[A] = {
    import org.fusesource.lmdbjni.Transaction

    // get a new transaction
    val tx: Transaction = instance.env.createWriteTransaction()

    println("tx = " + tx + " id = " + tx.getId)
    // get the key as an Array[Byte]. This is done by converting the key to a base64 string then converting that to bytes (so arbitary objects can be made into keys)
    val k = key.render
    println("Key = " + key + " Rendered = " + new String(k))
    // instantiate a result value, so there is something if it fails
    var res: LMDBEither[A] = NoResult.left // initialise the result as a failure to begin with
    try {
        res = for { // This for construction chains together operations that return LMDBEithers into one LMDBEither
          bytes <- LMDBEither(db.get(tx, k)) // error occurs in this Database.get() call
          _ = println("bytes = " + bytes)
          a <- sa.fromBytes(safeRetrieve(bytes)) // sa is effectively an unmarshaller/unmarshaller object which converts Vector[Byte] => LMDBEither[A]
          _ = println("a = " + a)
          res <- compute(a) // get the next value for the value at the key
          _ = println("res = " + res)
          _ <- LMDBEither(db.put(tx, k, sa.toBytes(res).toArray))
        } yield a // effectively, if all these steps worked, res == Right(a)
        res // return the result
    } finally {
      // Make sure you either commit or rollback to avoid resource leaks.
      if (res.isRight) tx.commit() // if the result is not an error (ie Either.isRight is true)
      else tx.abort()
      tx.close()
    }
  }
```

Where `LMDBEither[A]` is an alias for `Either[E, A]` for a specific error type E, and `LMDBEither(x)` is a function that lifts an expression that might throw exceptions during execution into an LMDBEither, catching any exceptions.
the function `safeRetrieve` converts a possibly `null` `Array[Byte]` into a definitely not null `Vector[Byte]`, as follows:

```
  private def safeRetrieve(bytes: Array[Byte]): Vector[Byte]  =       
  Option(bytes).fold(Vector[Byte]()){ // if the array is null, convert to an empty vector, otherwise call the array's wrapper's vector
      arr =>
        println("Vector = " + arr.toVector)
        arr.toVector
  }
```

To the best of my knowledge, this does not modify the memory where the array is stored (LMDB's protected memory)

The values printed up to and including the crash are as follows:

```
tx = org.fusesource.lmdbjni.Transaction@391cec1f id = 15104
Key = Vector(Objects) Rendered = 84507411390877848991196161
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x000000018002453f,     pid=10220, tid=7268
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_60-b27) (build 1.8.0_60-b27)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.60-b23 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [lmdbjni-64-0-7710432736670562378.4+0x2453f]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# C:\dev\PartIIProject\hs_err_pid10220.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
```

Which is more evidence that the `mdb_get()` fails.
the full contents of the file referenced are here: https://pastebin.com/v6AmFBjq

Again, I would be extremely grateful for the small chance that anyone could point me in the right direction. What next steps should I be taking?

Comment: I thought I'd add clarification that I'm not expecting magic wand answers, but I would be grateful for help on what the access violation means, common causes, and if other people more experienced using LMDB + JVM languages have had similar issues, etc

Comment: Xandros, "access violation" means that the program tried to access some invalid memory location. Typically this means either direct memory corruption or an attempt to use already freed pointer. Given that you use JNI the LMDB must be implemented in some VM-based language where both kinds of errors are quite possible. However this might be a bug in the LMDB JNI as well or a bug introduced by your wrong usage of it. It is really hard to advice how to help you. Probably the best approach will be trying to produce and publish a really small [mcve] so everyone can reproduce and debug this issue.

Comment: One likely cause is for the LMDB environment/db to be closed in a different thread. Ongoing reads/writes will then be accessing invalid memory locations.